# How to handle the exception & retry route startup in Camel DSL while starting endpoints

Tags: spring, apache-camel, dsl

I am using a kafka consumer configured in camel DSL to listen for a Kafka topic. There is another application (server) where kafka is setup and which is producing data on this topic.

```
<camel:endpoint id='docInfo' uri='kafka:${camel.kafka_broker}?    topic=${camel.kafka_topic}&zookeeperConnect=${camel.kafka_zookeeper}&groupId=${k    afka_groupId}&clientId=${camel.kafka_host}&consumerStreams=${camel.kafka_threads    }' />
   <!-- The camel route to consume the message -->
    <camel:route id="consumeDocInfoFromKafka" autoStartup="false">
    <camel:from uri='ref:docInfo' />
   </camel:route>
```

Everything is working except one scenario where during startup if endpoints are down, loading of camelContext fails and whole application gets down.
I want a solution so that I can handle this exception in my code and retry to connect after a particular time so that whenever server is up my consumer can connect to that.

Comment: I have one more doubt, If I call this function to get the route from my thread (to start the route )
     camelContext.getRoute("consumeDocInfo");

this will return null for few seconds even though context is already up, but after few secs it returns me the route.

Is there any specific reason route takes time to initialize or something?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to catch wiring issues within the route itself. Its a bootstrapping problem. However, you can use the Java DSL or a bundle Activator to wire up the route and then catch any issues at route startup time.

Regrind your second note: routes are fired up in a separate thread (they have to be in order to handle receive/consume). The startup delay could be first-time wiring of those jars in the JVM or specific consumer endpoint initialization (in this case the Kafka client library connecting to the Kafka server). Camel itself is very lightweight and does not have any heavy weight processes during initialization of contexts and routes.